# Pass multiple JSON objects to MVC3 action method

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

JQuery code:

```
    //This passes NULL for "CategoryID", "CategoryName", "ProductID", "ProductName"
     $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            var CategoryModel = {
                CategoryID: 1,
                CategoryName: "Beverage"
            };
            var ProductModel = {
                ProductID: 1,
                ProductName: "Chai"
            };
            var data1 = {};

            data1["cat"] = CategoryModel;
            data1["prd"] = ProductModel;

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data1);

            $.ajax({
                url: url + '/Complex/ModelTwo', //This works but property values are null 
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',           
                data: { "cat": CategoryModel, "prd": ProductModel }, //jsonData,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
```

MVC Code (C#):

```
     public class ComplexController : Controller
    {
        public string ModelOne(Category cat)
        {
            return "this took single model...";
        }

        public string ModelTwo(Category cat, Product prd)
        {
            return "this took multiple model...";
        }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the issue is, I couldn't get it working by passing "CategoryMode", "ProductModel" into "ModelTwo" action method. The JQuery post correctly identifies the action method "ModelTwo" but "cat", "prd" property values are null. "CategoryID", "CategoryName", "ProductID", "ProductName" all are null despite hitting that method.

```
    //THIS ONE WORKS FINE...

     $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            var CategoryModel = {
                CategoryID: 1,
                CategoryName: "Beverage"
            };
            var ProductModel = {
                ProductID: 1,
                ProductName: "Chai"
            };
            var data1 = {};

            data1["cat"] = CategoryModel;
            data1["prd"] = ProductModel;

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data1);

            $.ajax({
                url: url + '/Complex/ModelOne', //This works
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',           
                data: CategoryModel,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
```

So what's wrong with my first JQuery call to "ModelTwo" action method?

I spent lots of time figuring this out, but not sure what's going on. There is no issue with routing here because I can land on the right action method...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could send them as JSON request:

```
var categoryModel = {
    categoryID: 1,
    categoryName: "Beverage"
};
var productModel = {
    productID: 1,
    productName: "Chai"
};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ModelTwo")',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    // It is important to set the content type
    // request header to application/json because
    // that's how the client will send the request
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ cat: categoryModel, prd: productModel }),
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method that I am using in my example is natively built-in all modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

This should correctly bind to the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModelTwo(Category cat, Product prd)
{
    return Json(new { message = "this took multiple model..." });
}
```

But I would recommend you defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Category Cat { get; set; }
    public Product Prd { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModelTwo(MyViewModel model)
{
    return Json(new { message = "this took a single view model containing multiple models ..." });
}
```

and of course the client side code stays the same.

Comment: This is great!!!!!! IT worked. It was working just fine WITHOUT "ContentType" setting for the single parameter version, but double. The only change I had to make was to make the stringify on data being passed like you mentioned instead of the whole model itself "JSON.stringify({ cat: CategoryModel, prd: ProductModel })" helped a lot. You made my day Darin! Thank you so much!

Comment: I got it working by having a wrapper class that has "get set" of the Category, and Product class. It was working just fine for the single parameter version but when I pass two parameters. But anyways, your suggestion helped, I had to add contentType to be json for the two parameterized action method. Thank you!

Comment: Does this work in Firefox? It works in IE just fine but firefox. It's not landing in the action controller, when I used fiddler to find out what the data is being passed to the controller, just blank. BTW, my controller action method resides in different project, so it's cross domain posting. It works just fine as long as the action method takes one parameter but two. Something wrong in passing data to the controller cross domain.

Comment: @SensbileDude, you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests.

Comment: it successfully works across domain if it's single parameter, I got it working in all the browser. But when I have two parameters that are of class types, serializing them to land on correct controller is not working. It's the issue of matching the data that's transmitted to the controller. It works in IE but others.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Does this also work when talking to ASP.NET Web API?
Using your suggested method returns following exception:
Can't bind multiple parameters ('p' and 'addr') to the request's content.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException".

Do I have to implement a custom action binding when using Web API ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It works but very cumbersome, on the clientside you have to wrap the different objects into an array and the controller action must have a paramater of type arraylist. Then you can get the objects via index and then you need to deserialize them using newtonsoft dll.....
That way I am assaulting Web API I guess...

Answer (score -1):

```
 var a = $("#a").serialize();
            var b = $("#b").serialize();
            var c = $("#c").serialize();


     $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Controller/Method1")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: a+b+c,
    success: function (success) {
    // do something
    }

    });

    // in Controller
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Method1(abc a, bcd b, xyz c)
    {
    }

// where abc, bcd xyz are class
```