# AJAX Post Multiple Data to ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing problem while posting multiple objects via ajax jquery to MVC 4 controller. It has been weeks but I can't seem to find a solution.
I tried several approaches, sometimes the filterModel object is null and sometimes string parameters are null (doesn't matter even if I stringify of if I specify contentType or not)

What I want?
I want to pass three objects: 1. filterModel 2.testparamA 3.testparamB
What should I do to pass all three objects to MVC controller? What do I need to write in data: so I get all 3 object values?

The simplest Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string testparamA, string testparamB, FilterModel filter)
{
    using (RBSystemEntities repository = new RBSystemEntities())
    {
        return Json(new {
            DataList = repository.Items.Select(x => new {x.PKID, x.ItemName}).ToList(),
            Result = "OK"
        });
    }
}
```

The simplest View

```
var filterModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new FilterModel("ItemName", "Pepperoni Pizza")))
//filterModel = JSON.stringify(filterModel);

function testme() {
    // post the javascript variable back to the controller 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Menu/Test',
        type: 'POST',
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            filter: filterModel,
            testparamA: 'A value',
            testparamB: 'B value'
        }, // with this approach I get filterModel null in the controller however testparamA and testparamB has values
        data: filterModel, // with this approach I get values for filterModel but I can't pass testparamA and testparamB
        success: function (result) {
            // TODO: do something with the results
            alert('success');
        }
    });
}
testme();
```

The simplest FilterModel class

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public FilterModel() { }
    public FilterModel(string filtercolumn, string filtervalue)
    {
        this.FilterColumn = filtercolumn;
        this.FilterValue = filtervalue;
        this.FilterColumnCriteria = "=";
    }
    public string FilterColumn { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public string FilterColumnCriteria { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you write a ModelBinder for `FilterModel`?

Comment: Are you saying data: JSON.stringify({ fm: filterModel, ta: testparamA, tb: testparamA }) doesn't work? Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558848/pass-multiple-json-objects-to-mvc3-action-method

Comment: @PhilippM I didn't write a ModelBinder. It should be binded automatically by MVC because data: filterModel works perfectly and sends data to MVC. But data: {filter: filterModel,testparamA: 'A value',testparamB: 'B value'} doesn't works

Comment: If you have a ModelBinder, MVC will distinguish between flat parameters and the object for `FilterModel` I think, but I can't test it now.

Comment: @PaulZahra Thanks. now i realize that i should stringify the whole thing not just filterModel :) Glad it worked :)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/310136/508479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you don't mind me posting my comment (which was helpful) as an answer...

If you use stringify as follows it should work...

```
JSON.stringify({ fm: filterModel, ta: testparamA, tb: testparamA })
```

Comment: Works well using $.ajax post with { datatype: 'json' ...}

Answer (score 0):

@PaulZahra guided me to the right direction.

> Below changes fixed my problem:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // uncomment this
data: JSON.stringify({ filter: filterModel, testparamA: 'A value', testparamB: 'B value' }), //stringify whole thing and not just c# class
```