# SignalR message being sent to every opened page instance. How to send to only exact one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

This question has been answered multiple times, but I'm still not getting it.

I am using an example from this page: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D

However, I've modified the `SendProgress` method a bit, to send the message only to the specific connection, not all clients:

```
 public static void SendProgress(string connectionId, string progressMessage, int progressCount, int totalItems)
    {                   
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<RealTimeProgressBar.ProgressHub>();          
        var percentage = (progressCount * 100) / totalItems;           
        hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).AddProgress(progressMessage, percentage + "%");
    }
```

I am getting connection Id from overrided OnConnected method:

```
 public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Environments.ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

I'm currently storing it in a static class `Environments`, I guess there is a better way for doing so, but I don't know it yet :)

The question is, when I open for example two instances of my web page in browser, the progress bar is still being shown for all of these instances, though the connectionIds on these pages are different (checked it in `SendProgress` function).

What is wrong here?

Perhaps, I should change something in js code?

```
$(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
            console.log(progress);

            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            progress.client.AddProgress = function (message, percentage) {
                ProgressBarModal("show", message +  " " + percentage);
                $('#ProgressMessage').width(percentage);
                if (percentage == "100%") {
                    ProgressBarModal();
                }
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
                console.log(connectionId);
            });

        });
```

As i'm not really sure if js funcs really uses `Environments.ConnectionId` or smthing else..
Thanks!

Edit: What I want to achive is to send unique progress bars for every opened page. e.g. when I press the button on a first page, I'm starting to collect data and progress bar reflects that. I also open another page in a browser, and collect data from another source, so the progress bar should reflect that for this page as well.

my controller method:

```
 public ActionResult Generate(InputDataViewModel viewModel, string connectionId)
        {
...
            var Tasks = getResultsWithProgressBar(viewModel.jobId, connectionId);
...
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = job.JobDataId });   
        }
```

and somewhere inside this "getResult" is a function that actually calls progress bar(SendProgress)

Comment: Take a loot at this here (I haven't used it myself) https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection#sending-to-a-specific-connection

Comment: How is `Environments.ConnectionId` defined?  Looks like a static property?  If that's the case you're stomping the connection id on each new connection.

Comment: yes, it's a static property, but I don't really get how it happens, I definetely see that for two opened pages connection Id's are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change should work fine.
You are using a static ConnectionId, so only your last browser, the browser you opened last(or connected last) will see the progress bar as well as updates.

This is the only one i made apart apart from adding in the static Environment.ConnectionId.

```
        //PUSHING DATA TO ALL CLIENTS
        // hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, percentage + "%");
        hubContext.Clients.Client(Environments.ConnectionId).AddProgress(progressMessage, percentage + "%");
```

So if you open 10 browser windows and click on the button on all those, one by one, only the browser you initially opened last will see the the progress bar as well as updates, but **it will see updates from all the 10 browsers shown on that single progress bar**!

It is fun to see though!

When I tried your code, I saw the behavior you observed initially. But when I opened two separate Incognito browsers, I see the correct behavior. Close the IIS express site, rebuild and retry it.

Edit:
If you need each tab to have its own progress bar, then you will need one of the two approaches below:

- A way to identify which rest request came from which connectionId. If you want to continue using the current code. Just pass in the connection Id to the LongRunningProcess. Client code below:

  ```
   var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
  var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;                
  $.getJSON("/Home/LongRunningProcess", 
  {"connectionId":connectionId},
  function (data) {
      if (!data) {
          alert("Success");
      }
      else
      {
          alert(data);
      }    
  });
  ```

Server code would be:

```
    public JsonResult LongRunningProcess(string connectionId)
    {
        //THIS COULD BE SOME LIST OF DATA
        int itemsCount = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i <= itemsCount; i++)
        {
            //SIMULATING SOME TASK
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            //CALLING A FUNCTION THAT CALCULATES PERCENTAGE AND SENDS THE DATA TO THE CLIENT
            Functions.SendProgress(connectionId, "Process in progress...", i , itemsCount);
        }

        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

- The other option is to call a signalr method on the server instead of a rest method. Create a new hub method in the ProgressHub like below:

  ```
   public void LongRunningHubMethod()
  {
      //THIS COULD BE SOME LIST OF DATA
      int itemsCount = 100;

      for (int i = 0; i <= itemsCount; i++)
      {
          //SIMULATING SOME TASK
          Thread.Sleep(500);

          //CALLING A FUNCTION THAT CALCULATES PERCENTAGE AND SENDS THE DATA TO THE CLIENT
          Functions.SendProgress(Context.ConnectionId, "Process in progress...", i, itemsCount);
      }
  }
  ```

The client would then just call in the hub method on click like below:

```
     var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
    var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
    progress.invoke('LongRunningHubMethod');
```

Comment: that's not really what I am trying to achive, I've edited my question.
I just want to have all page instances get individual progress bars for requests made on these pages. Not sending one progress bar to all/one page. Page 1 have progress bar #1, page 2 recieves progress bar #2, and so on.

Comment: In that case you will need to call a signalR server method instead of the REST method you are calling-"LongRunningProcess". I've updated the answer for that requirement.

Comment: I'm not really seeing the update, have you missed it?

Comment: That's too complicated for me, sadly, I'm not getting it. 
I've edited my question and added my controller method: so if I use 1st approach, how would I pass my viewModel inside controller method with that javascript call? 
The 2nd option..how is that going to work? My controller will create hub instance, than call that hub method? is it going to be poor architecture? and again I would have to parse my viewModel inside that method..
It's complete mishmash for me, why just can't signalR send messages only to current connectionId? Like `progress.client(connection).AddProgress` would be ideal

Comment: If you use 1st approach, to pass in multiple data from the javascript side, you just need to add multiple objects into that javascript data that you're sending. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558848/pass-multiple-json-objects-to-mvc3-action-method.

Comment: Signalr IS sending the updates to a single connection in both these cases. The SendProgress method is specifically doing that with this line   
   hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).AddProgress(...)   . The problem you're trying to solve is finding out the exact connectionId of the current request. The basic point is the MVC Controller does not have access to the hubContext and so cannot possibly know the current connectionID. Also once connected the connection will be a websocket whereas your controller will be serving http requests.

Comment: If you need to return full MVC views in response to methods and you just need occasional updates during that method call(like you pointed) then you should go with option 1. SignalR is more for message exchanges between the client and the server and not for sending Views through the message. Exchanging json objects is its best usage. You can in turn form html out of that json data or embed it into your view somewhere. But if you already have a complete MVC site and just looking to enhance your responsiveness, Option 1 should be fine.